# If URL is equal to X then do this

Tags: php

Is there any way I can echo some code if the URL matches a set URL?

I know I can do this using the menu ID such as:

```
//This is the code for the page with menu ID 3
$menuID = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id ;
    if ($menuID == '3')
    {
        echo '';
    }
```

But I want to be able to echo a piece of code if the URL matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.

If I use the following:

```
//Get the full URL for sharing purposes
$uri = JFactory::getURI();
$absolute_url = $uri->toString();
```

This will get me the current URL. I can the put an if statement in for this, such as:

```
if ($absolute_url == 'http://mydomain.com/the/url/i/want/to/match/')
    {
        echo '';
    }
```

Comment: For me it makes little sense to a fixed domain name. Why not something generic that catches the query parameters? Also how do you deal with with http(s), www? You can have a big IF.

Comment: I agree, and usually I wouldn't implement anything on an exact URL, but this was the requirement on this piece of work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are only using a `http` URL and **not** `https`, you can use the following to get the URL:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

The to perform the check, you could use this:

```
if($url == "http://www.example.com/ooga/booga") {
    echo "match";
}
```

### Update:

Using Joomla's API which would be a more appropriate method as it checks for `https` and performs a small cleanup of invalid characters to prevent injections. To do so, you can simply use the following:

```
$url = JUri::getInstance();
echo $url->toString();

if($url == "http://www.example.com/ooga/booga") {
    echo "match";
}
```

Comment: Please never access directly the globals ($_SERVER or whatever). Use the Joomla API either using JUri or JInput.

Comment: @Bakual - Indeed, I forgot about the cleanup that Joomla performs when getting the URL else it does more or less exactly what I have provided in the first section of my question. Anyway, updated my answer with a Joomla appoach

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit what the exact purpose is. Does it have to work for SEF and non SEF URLs? Is the purpose looking for a specific view?

I would probably use JInput and check for a given component, view and id if I have to match a specific article for example. This way it doesn't matter with which URL the user visits the page. It works with SEF enabled or disabled, doesn't matter. It also works for multiple URLs pointing to the same article.
Like this:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

if ($jinput->get('option') == 'com_content'
        && $jinput->get('view') == 'article'
        && $jinput->get('id') == 123)
{
    echo 'foo';
}
```

But if you really have to match an exact URL and ignore all variants, then your solution using `JFactory::getURI();` is the proper way.